# Should I Skip Recovery Installation Step From CyanogenMod ROM

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms

I have a rooted Galaxy S2 (i9100) . I've root it with CF-ROOT . Now superSU and CWM installed and there is a yellow exclamation on boot screen. When i boot my phone with VOLUME UP + HOME + POWER button, there is a screen which has title : CWM-based Recovery v5.5.0.4 .

Other details about my phone :

- Model : GT-i9100
- Android : 4.0.4
- Baseband Version : I9100XXLQ6
- Kernel Version : 3.0.15-I9100XWLPU-CL975203 dpi@DELL167 #3 SMP PREEMT Mon Jul 30 18:18:51 KST 2012 ***(This is weird because i'm from Turkey and I9100XWLPU firmware not Turkey's firmware. This firmware installed to my phone at Samsung's local technical service. [Here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/1/?model=GT-I9100&pcode=TUR) a list of Turkey's firmwares.)***
- Build : IMM76D.XWLPU

Now here my questions :

1. Should i skip **Installing a custom recovery on Galaxy S II** section on here : http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_i9100 ? (Because i have CWM recovery mode)
2. I'm worried about warning on this screen : http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/I9100_Info . Warning starting with `Some second-generation Samsung Exynos devices are potentially susceptible to a "superbrick" ...  It is highly recommended you do not perform this operation while using a stock kernel` . I know meaning of bricking but not sure about superbrick . Also i couldn't understand what they mean with stock kernel. Is this really dangerous ? Can't we (or Samsung's technical service) fix superbricked phone?

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether you're susceptible by installing this app - [Exynos Mem Bug Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lowlevel.exynosmembug).

Next - installing a custom kernel isn't all that difficult and neither is it too risky *if* you know what you're doing.

For the S2 - Siyah kernel and Dorimanx kernel are the two most popular ones. However, the latest kernels are meant for Android 4.2.x and higher. So, use the correct version for your OS. Should you decide to install a custom ROM like CyanogenMod or Paranoid Android etc., it will install a kernel with a recovery too (as an example - Siyah and Dorimanx - which is based on Siyah - have a touch based recovery, so you can scroll through the options by touch instead of repeatedly clicking the volume buttons to scroll as in CyanogenMod or others).

The CF-Root kernel that you installed to root the S2 is a modified stock kernel, IIRC. Therefore, it might be susceptible to the Superbrick / eMMC bug.

Comment: ,i just install mem bug checker app and result  : device IS affected . Is it mean i can't / shouldn't install Cyanogenmod ?

Comment: Also as a second question, you said cfroot kernel bad for Cyanogenmod. So should i install siyah or dorimanx before try cyanogenmod.

Comment: No...my device is also affected by the brick bug. It's rare and it only affects devices that are running the stock Samsung kernel. If you do flash another kernel / ROM, your device will no longer be susceptible to this bug. And to clarify - I have NEVER said that cfroot is bad for CM. Once you install CM, it'll install CM kernel.

Comment: i should install another ROM and then install CM over this. Did  i understand it well? Sorry for English

Comment: No...you can choose to continue with the original, stock Samsung ROM and merely install a compatible kernel. If you do choose to install CyanogenMod, it will install the CM kernel as well.

Comment: But you said, it's a little risky using stock kernel (also there is a warning on page about this). Sorry maybe i misunderstood because of my English.

Comment: You are susceptible to the superbrick bug due to the stock Samsung kernel. There's always a miniscule risk that something might go wrong. In 99.99% of cases, things are never so bad that the device can't be brought back to life. There are thousands of users who have successfully rooted their devices/ installed kernels / ROMs etc. Everyone starts somewhere, @Eray . HOWEVER, if you're at all uncomfortable, don't proceed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8752/discussion-between-sparx-and-eray)